# Group neighboring values using linq

Tags: .net, linq, group-by, aggregate

I have a sorted list of int values, and I want to make groups neighboring values. The values, where next value is nextvalue>= prevValue+1 are neighbors.

For example:
List:

```
{1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10}
```

Groups will be:

```
{1,2,3}
{5,6}
{8,9,10}
```

Could this be done using linq?

This can be easily done without linq - by iterating the list, but I'm wondering if linq has solution for this.

Comment: Is linq a requirement?

Comment: Yes, Linq is requirement.

Comment: Are you sure you have the condition correct? If `nextvalue >= prevValue+1` then 3 and 5 are neighbours: prevVal = 3, nextVal = 5 -> prevVal + 1 = 4 -> 5 >= 4 is true hence prevVal = 3 and nextVal = 5 are neighbours. Shouldn't it be: `nextvalue == prevValue+1` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
private static void GroupToNeighboursTest()
{
    var numbers = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10 };
    var neighbours = numbers
        .Zip(numbers.Skip(1), Tuple.Create)
        .Aggregate(new List<List<int>> { new List<int> { numbers.First() } }, (result, i) =>
        {
            if (i.Item1 == i.Item2 - 1)
            {
                result.Last().Add(i.Item2);
            }
            else
            {
                result.Add(new List<int> { });
                result.Last().Add(i.Item2);
            }

            return result;
        });
}
```

[image]

Comment: I just tested this code and it doesn't produce the output asked for in the question.

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
var result =
    items
        .Skip(1)
        .Aggregate(
            new [] { items.Take(1).ToList() }.ToList(),
            (acc, item) =>
            {
                if (acc.Last().Last() == item - 1)
                {
                    acc.Last().Add(item);   
                }
                else
                {
                    acc.Add(new [] { item }.ToList());
                }
                return acc;
            });
```

I get this result:

[image: result]

As a side note, I do like getting into the habit of building lists like this `new [] { item }.ToList()` as it allows building lists of anonymous types. Very useful in many LINQ queries.

Answer (score 1):

If you must use Linq, you could consider the `Aggregate` method.

```
x.Aggregate(new List<List<int>> { new List<int>() }, (soFar, next) => {
     if (soFar.Last().Contains(next - 1)) {
         soFar.Last().Add(next);   
     } else {
         soFar.Add(new List<int> { next });
     }
     return soFar; 
});
```

Comment: `Contains` is an O(n) operation. Also this seems to return an extra empty group in the beginning.

Comment: I think, from my understanding of the question, that you can change the `.Contains(...)` line to `if (soFar.Last().Last() == next - 1) {`.

Answer (score 0):

I only have a non linq solution for this (if I've understood the problem correctly). Hope it helps.

```
void Main()
{
    var list = new List<int>{1,2,3,5,6,8,9,10};
    GetData(list).Dump();
}

public IEnumerable<List<int>> GetData(IEnumerable<int> data)
{
    int prev = 0;
    var g = new List<int>();
    foreach (var item in data)
    {
        if(item - prev > 1 && g.Count > 0)
        {
            yield return g;
            g = new List<int>();
        }
        g.Add(item);
        prev = item;
    }
    yield return g;
}
```